# How can I refresh the Taskbar programatically in Windows 10 and higher?

Tags: windows, refresh, explorer, taskbar

Right off the bat, please don't judge too harshly, I'm still relatively new to this forum and not too practiced at formulating my question yet :)

Background:

Because I have to install Windows and do it's configuration on new computers very often, I found some settings are always the same but anyway important (like showing filetyype endings, disable cortana and news & interests, pin Word/Excel to taskbar, etc.)

Problem:

My problem is about the task-view button - I set it hidden in registry (but let the chance to reactivate it anytime). Sure - you can make a change to the taskbar settings manually, but per program this won't work. Because of such changes won't adapt until reboot or restart of "explorer.exe" under normal circumstances:

**How can I disable the taskview button (or refresh the taskbar in general) programmatically without killing any process?**

And no - other similar questions don't help, since they're related to either the systray or old OS' it's solution are not longer working.

My Environment:

Windows 10 32/64-Bit 21H1
I'm happy with pretty much any solution, no matter the program language.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Use Spy++ to check if the Settings app broadcasts a message, WM_SETTINGSCHANGE with a specific lParam perhaps.

Comment: Hm, there are many entries only for Taskview button (calles "Active Applications") when hiding it, but only one with the beginning you mentioned:
WM_SETTINGCHANGE wFlag:0000 pszMetrics:0309E388

Comment: pszMetrics:0309E388 is a string at that memory location, you need to find out what it is, either with a debugger or if this is a broadcast message, just a simple test application...

Comment: I don't know exactly how and if I'm on the right path. Even the entries with no parameters in my C++ app aren't recognized by Spy++
[e.g. SendMessage(NULL, (LPARAM) "WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED lpwp:0309E430", NULL, (LPARAM)L"TrayButton");]
Can you find any mistake in this line or give me an example, maybe for C++?

Comment: Where did "TrayButton" come from? Why are you sending to NULL? Send to HWND_BROADCAST

Comment: NULL is corrected to HWND_BROADCAST, the "TrayButton" was the name in Spy++ after the name in "", I don't know how to get the correct name, this was similiar to names other used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DWORD data = 0;
SHSetValueA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Advanced", "ShowTaskViewButton", REG_DWORD, &data, 4);
SendNotifyMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, (LPARAM) TEXT("TraySettings"));
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I got managed to change the registry dword (first line), but taskbar  refreshes neither the TaskView button nor any other section in taskbar (at least not visible to me)

Comment: Works for me on Win10

Comment: Then it has to be a mistake related to my project. Maybe you can show me your whole cpp file so I can find the error faster...

Comment: If it compiles it should work.

Comment: Yes it compiles but do nothing. For recent tests I enabled e.g. support for older OS like XP and such things (BTW I'm using VS2017), maybe in my header there could missing also something (I'm not very good in programming, I'm far more experienced in scripting.
So, can you show me the full code so I can compare?

Comment: We're speaking about the "Active Applications" part on the taskbar (TaskView-Button), not the section which is called "Taskbar" (the part with the shortcuts) and not the systray, do we? Because I only need to update this little button and believing Spy++ it is an own entry full independent of the rest of the taskbar.

Comment: This changes the task view button, the setting controlled by `ShowTaskViewButton`.

Comment: my not, can you send me then your compiled exe or project files via temporary cloud link?

Comment: This one tries to toggle on and off every time: http://sredna.users.sf.net/public/TaskbarToggleTaskViewButton.exe Keep in mind that all of this is internal Explorer functionality and can stop working at any time. Microsoft does not expose a public API to change the taskbar features.

Comment: Fantastic, it works! Yes, I'm aware of that it can become useless at anytime with updates. But that applies to everything in general. Once again, your code does a great job!

Comment: OK, thanks for advice (is marked now)